# Porting GPUImage filter subclasses to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, gpuimage

I'm trying to port an app from Objective-C to Swift, but I'm having problems with a subclass of GPUImageFilter.

In Obj-C, subclassing GPUImageFilter and using a different fragment shader was as easy as

```
- (id)init;
{
    NSString *fragmentShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestShader" ofType:@"fsh"];
    NSString *fragmentShaderString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fragmentShaderPathname encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    if (!(self = [super initWithFragmentShaderFromString:fragmentShaderString]))
    {
        return nil;
    }

    return self;
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this in Swift. This is my new initializer:

```
override init() {
    let fragmentShaderPathname = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TestShader", ofType: "fsh")!
    let fragmentShaderString = NSString(contentsOfFile: fragmentShaderPathname, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

    super.init(fragmentShaderFromString: fragmentShaderString)
}
```

As soon as this gets called, the app crashes with this error message:
`/Users/peterwunder/Documents/XCode/welp/welp/GPUImageTestFilter.swift: 12: 7: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(vertexShaderFromString:fragmentShaderFromString:)' for class 'welp.GPUImageTestFilter'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting problem! You're getting tripped up due to the differences in initialization between Swift and Objective-C. If the `GPUImageFilter` class were written in Swift, the compiler wouldn't let you have this setup, but since you're mixing & matching it doesn't complain until runtime. Here's what's happening when you try to instantiate your subclass:

1. You call `let myFilter = CustomGPUImageFilter()`
2. Your `init()` loads the shader string and calls `super.init(fragmentShaderString: "foo")`
3. `GPUImageFilter.init(fragmentShaderString:)` calls `[self initWithVertexShaderFromString:@"bar" fragmentShaderFromString:@"foo"]`.

What type is `self` in that last line? If you're calling from your subclass's initializer, the type of `self` is actually that of your subclass: `CustomGPUImageFilter`. So the initializer that gets called is actually on your subclass. Why is this a problem?

Unfortunately, Swift classes don't automatically inherit the initializers from their superclass if they define their own *designated* initializers, which is what your `init()` is. So the runtime tries to call `CustomGPUImageFilter.init(vertexShaderFromString:fragmentShaderFromString:)`, doesn't find it, and crashes with that error message.

Happily, the fix is quite simple. If you mark your initializer as `convenience init`, you'll no longer be defining a designated initializer, which means your subclass *will* inherit the initializers from `GPUImageFilter`. Then in step 3 above, the runtime will find the inherited initializer on your subclass and execute without a problem. Note that you'll need to call `self.init...` instead of `super.init...`:

```
convenience override init() {
    let fragmentShaderPathname = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TestShader", ofType: "fsh")!
    let fragmentShaderString = NSString(contentsOfFile: fragmentShaderPathname, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

    self.init(fragmentShaderFromString: fragmentShaderString)
}
```

For more about this process, read the section on [class inheritance and initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_324) in the Swift documentation. The process is *significantly* different from Objective-C.

Comment: Dang. I expected that things would be fundamentally different, but I didn't expect _this_. :D Thanks!